# Selenium gets stuck in browser.get()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This code opens Firefox and downloads a file. But when the download completes, it seems to get stuck in the browser.get() process meaning it does not close the browser and the code does not stop running. How can I make it close the browser upon successful (or failure to) download?

```
from selenium import webdriver
with webdriver.Firefox() as browser:
    browser.get("http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip")
browser.quit()
```

I know I can manually get this sample file. I want to automate this process for large scale use in a few websites that deny GET requests even with the correct user agent information.

I am using PyCharm 2023.1.3 (Community Edition), Python 3.9 (64-bit), Firefox 114.0.2 64-bit, and Win 10.

Comment: _ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com didn’t send any data._ + _ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE_

Comment: Hmmm... that is odd that you don't get anything downloaded. I just re-ran the code and it downloads a 5MB zip file for me.